# systemd - restart without stop

Tags: systemd

I have a small problem. I have one program (let's call it master) which, internally, starts several programs (client1, client2 and client3) and detaches them.

Now, I want the main program to always stay online, so I wrote a systemd service file like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run the master
Before=runlevel2.target runlevel3.target runlevel4.target runlevel5.target
After=remote-fs.target systemd-journald-dev-log.socket all.target

[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=always
TimeoutSec=5min
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
KillMode=process
RemainAfterExit=no
SysVStartPriority=5
ExecStart=/home/user/start_master.sh start
ExecStop=/home/user/start_master.sh stop
PIDFile=/var/run/mymaster.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The starting script is like this one:

```
#! /bin/sh

PIDFILE=/var/run/mymaster.pid

do_start() {
    /home/user/master >/dev/null 2>&1 &
    echo $!
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        PID=$(do_start)
        if [ -z $PID ]; then
                echo "Failed starting master"
                exit 2
        else
                echo $PID > $PIDFILE
        fi
        ;;
    stop)
        killall master client1 client2 client3 2>/dev/null
        rm $PIDFILE
        ;;
    restart)
        killall master 2>/dev/null
        $0 start
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 start|stop|restart" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
esac
```

My desired behavior is:

- on start: just start the master (it will take care of starting the clients)
- on restart (or when the master is shut down): kill the master program and restart it (since it will attach to the previous clients)
- on stop: kill the master program and all the clients

Now, with this setup, everything works fine: when I start the service, this is what I see:

```
$ systemctl status master.service
● master.service - Run the master
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/master.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-10-19 16:16:33 CEST; 5s ago
  Process: 4161 ExecStop=/home/user/start_master.sh stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4198 ExecStart=/home/user/start_master.sh start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4200 (master)
   CGroup: /system.slice/master.service
           ├─4200 /home/user/master
           ├─4203 /home/user/client1
           ├─4205 /home/user/client2
           └─4209 /home/user/client3
```

Also the stop runs fine. BUT... when I want to restart it (either by calling restart or by manually killing the master program) systemd executes the ExecStop instead of the restart command, thus killing all the clients too.

Is there a way to achieve what I wanted?

Best regards

PS. I'm using Debian 8.6.0 x64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

systemd does not have a notion of a restart that is not just stop-if-running+start. You might be able to use `ExecReload=` and then use `systemctl reload` instead of restart, but the question is why you need this?

Why do you restart the master without restarting the clients? For that matter, what does the master actually do? Your start script leads me to believe that you are trying to do process supervision again, which I would advise against - systemd can do that, so use it.

I would recommend that you instead try to figure out how you can start the clients via systemd.

In any case, your start script is completely superfluous. It uses PID files and all sorts of stuff that is absolutely unnecessary because systemd can already do all that stuff. I suggest removing it and instead just using "ExecStart=/home/user/master" in your .service file (if the master is necessary after all), then adjust the Type= from "forking" to "simple". Remove the "ExecStop" and "PIDFile".

I recommend https://jdebp.eu/FGA/systemd-house-of-horror/tomcat.html as further reading.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Anyway yes, I was trying to implement a supervisor, but using systemd was not a good idea because I needed to have more control on which clients should be started and when (so the master had to handle this). It's better if the clients are left running because this way they will be able to continue to receive data and then connect back to master. The script, however, was automatically generated when I switched the system from init.d to systemd (and that's why it was considered forking).

Comment: The master can still kill the clients (and they'll stay down) if they're systemd services, provided they have "Restart=on-failure" (or on-abnormal). What you need here is to get the clients out of the master's systemd service, and the easiest way to do that is to make them systemd units that master starts.

Comment: Ok, I'll think about it. BTW is there a way to control systemd from a C/C++ program instead of using system calls to launch systemctl?

Comment: There's the [dbus apis](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/dbus/), and I'd imagine libsystemd also has functions for it.

Comment: I hate that the only answer to this is trying to talk him out of it. _Maybe_ that's the correct response in this particular scenario, but another _valid_ scenario that exactly matches this is Docker. If I want my service to spin up a new container with zero downtime, I need to avoid calling `stop`; I just want to run the `start` steps again. But systemd cannot avoid calling `stop`, and worse, won't call the `start` steps (pre+post) whilst it detects the service is already running.